# operating on a row in a pyspark column based on previous row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, iteration

I have a pyspark dataframe where I want to update the `drift_MS` column based on the value of another column `_MS`. However the math I would apply will differ based on the condition of `_MS`

Dataframe:

```
|SEQ_ID |TIME_STAMP             |_MS               |
+-------+-----------------------+------------------+
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:24:20.525|NaN               |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:25:56.934|21.262409581399556|
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:27:43.264|27.247600203353613|
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:29:27.613|18.13528511851038 |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:31:10.512|2.520896614376871 |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:32:54.252|2.7081931585605541|
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:34:36.995|2.9832290627235505|
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:36:19.128|13.011968111650264|
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:38:10.919|17.762006254598797|
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:40:01.929|1.9661930950977457|
```

when `_MS` is >=3 and when the previous `_MS` is lesser than current `_MS` I want to increment the `drift_MS` by 100. But if `_MS` is <3 and previous `_MS` < current `_MS` I want to increment `drift_MS` by 1, otherwise keep the previous `drift_MS` value

Expected output:

```
|SEQ_ID |TIME_STAMP             |_MS               |drift_MS|
+-------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:24:20.525|NaN               |0       |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:25:56.934|21.262409581399556|0       |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:27:43.264|27.247600203353613|100     |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:29:27.613|18.13528511851038 |100     |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:31:10.512|2.520896614376871 |100     |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:32:54.252|2.7081931585605541|101     |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:34:36.995|2.9832290627235505|102     |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:36:19.128|13.011968111650264|202     |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:38:10.919|17.762006254598797|302     |
|3879826|2021-07-29 11:40:01.929|1.9661930950977457|302     |
```

I tried the following code:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

w1=Window.partitionBy('SEQ_ID').orderBy(col('TIME_STAMP').asc())
    
prev_MS = (f.lag(col('_MS'),1).over(w1))
prev_drift_MS = (f.lag(col('drift_MS'),1).over(w1))
    
df2=df.withColumn('drift_MS', when((col('_MS') < 3) & (prev_MS < col('_MS')), prev_drift_MS+1)\
.when((col('_MS') >= 3) & (prev_MS < col('_MS')), prev_drift_MS+100).otherwise(prev_drift_MS+0))
```

But the `drift_MS` column is either 100 or 1.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df.withColumn('drift_MS', 
  f.sum(
    when((col('_MS') < 3) & (prev_MS < col('_MS')), 1)
    .when((col('_MS') >= 3) & (prev_MS < col('_MS')), 100)
    .otherwise(0)
 ).over(w1))
```

Comment: Works like  a charm!

Comment: Cool. Glad it works for you!

Comment: sorry to be a pain. But is there a way to reset the `drift_MS` column to 0 if none of the conditions are satisfied? Currently, it just sums 0 which maintains the previous value. But it does not bring it down